# perforce exclude subfolder from diff

Tags: perforce

I have added an exclusion to my workspace which is called "dev-machine"

-//depot/DotNetProject/bin/... //dev-machine/bin/...

The bin folder now shows as excluded in p4diff but...

The differences are still showing i.e. diff 1 of 11 and the next and previous arrows are still taking me into those excluded folders.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Are you comparing a revision to "Workspace version on local disk"?

Comment: @raven latest revision to Workspace version on local disk, yes. Is that ok ?

Comment: I thought I was on to something, but after actually reproducing your problem, I can't say I can be of any help.  I assume you don't add bin directories to version control, so I find it surprising Perforce doesn't complain when you add a rule like `-//depot/DotNetProject/bin/... //dev-machine/bin/...` considering `//depot/DotNetProject/bin` doesn't even exist.  I'd contact Perforce tech support and see what they have to say about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the client-spec rule to remove the `bin` directory *after* making changes to the directory, and opening files in the directory? Perforce will still consider the files as mapped until you explicitly sync, and even then it'll prevent you from removing the file Perforce knows is open.

If Perforce already thinks the files in the `bin` directory are open (check with `p4 open`), your best bet may be to force-sync these files, or revert them, to remove them from your workspace. You'll end up with no files in your `bin` directory (at least, that Perforce is tracking), so you'll need to rebuild.

Comment: can you help me to change the p4 diff2 commandline to a c# p4command